# Why is my switch case not working for multiplication or addition

Tags: c, switch-statement

All of my other switch cases work but not addition or multiplication. I've tried switching the entry to an integer to see if the double calculation is the error but it did not work. I've changed it to accumulator = accumulator + entry, doesn't work. I don't see what else it could be.

```
double accumulator;
double entry;
char operation;

  do{

    printf("Value in the Accumulator = %lf\n", accumulator);
    scanf("%lf %c", &entry, &operation);

    if (entry == 0 && operation == '/'){
      printf("Can not divide by 0.\n");
      continue;
    }

    switch (operation){

    case 'S':
      accumulator = entry;
    case '+':
      accumulator += entry;
    case '-':
      accumulator -= entry;
    case '*':
      accumulator *= entry;
    case '/':
      accumulator /= entry;
    case 'E':
      break;
    default:
      printf("Unknown operator.\n");

    }

  }while(operation != 'E');

  printf("Value in the Accumulator = %lf\n", accumulator);

  printf("End of Calculations \n");

}


Result:

Value in the Accumulator = 0.000000
1000 S
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2 *
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2.0 *
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2 +
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2.0 +
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2 -
Value in the Accumulator = 998.000000
2 /
Value in the Accumulator = 499.000000
```

Comment: You need to add `break` for each `case`. Otherwise the code will continue to fall through to the next `case` until a `break` is encountered.

Comment: I added the breaks into every case but the addition calculation is wrong. Value in the Accumulator = 0.000000
1000 S
Value in the Accumulator = 1000.000000
2 +
Value in the Accumulator = 2002.000000
2 *
Value in the Accumulator = 4004.000000
2 -
Value in the Accumulator = 4002.000000

Comment: Perhaps you didn't make the correct changes or there are other bugs in your program. Suggest you post a new question with the updated code. Anyway, the way to find the problem is to run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements. The program is so small you should be able to find out much more before posting to SO.

Comment: Adding my addition case to the top fixed it. Not sure why but thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a tip: If you don't understand it then it's probably wrong. You may consider trying to work that out before it bites you later. If you can't work it out then post a new question with something like: Why does this code work but when I make this change which I think has no effect then it breaks?

Comment: also turn on all compiler warnings. It should shout at you when you forget to `break`